# Pandas DF Pivot/Transform/Vectorize Operation

Tags: python, pandas

Not an expert in Pandas, but I would like to know if there is a pythonic way to transform a series in a Pandas DF into columns headings with data consisting of arrays of "1s" and "0s".

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[254,300,300,300,850,850,1000],
                    'y':[57,12,34,45,8,45,9]})
```

x and y are vectors of the same size, and I would like "x" to be the index and the values in "y" to be columns headings, with "0" and "1" representing the presence/absence of y values in row x, so my transformed DF looks more or less like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `unstack` might be faster:

```
In [245]:

df1['z'] = 1
df1.groupby(['x', 'y']).count().unstack().fillna(0)
       z                    
y     8   9   12  34  45  57
x                           
254    0   0   0   0   0   1
300    0   0   1   1   1   0
850    1   0   0   0   1   0
1000   0   1   0   0   0   0

In [256]:

%timeit pd.crosstab(df1['x'], df1['y'])
100 loops, best of 3: 8.72 ms per loop
In [261]:

%%timeit
df1['z'] = 1
df1.groupby(['x', 'y']).count().unstack().fillna(0)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.75 ms per loop
In [262]:

%%timeit
df1['z'] = 1
df1.groupby(['x', 'y']).sum().unstack().fillna(0)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.88 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of options, of which one is to use the `crosstab` function specifically designed for this ([docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#cross-tabulations)):

```
In [2]: pd.crosstab(df1['x'], df1['y'])
Out[2]:
y     8   9   12  34  45  57
x
254    0   0   0   0   0   1
300    0   0   1   1   1   0
850    1   0   0   0   1   0
1000   0   1   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 1):

A less pythonic and very intuitive solution is this:

```
x_set = sorted(set(df1.x.tolist()))
y_set = sorted(set(df1.y.tolist()))

dF = pd.DataFrame({}, index=x_set, columns=y_set).fillna(0).sort_index()
dF.index.name = 'x'
dF.columns.name = 'y'
for idx, row in df1.iterrows():
    a = row['x']
    b = row['y']
    dF.loc[a, b] += 1
```

Which produces this:

[image]